# Flowgear endpoint not working

Tags: flowgear

Trying to test a sample endpoint for a workflow that I configured as follows:
POST https://mycompany.flowgear.net/bizrules/validation/gstCheck/?name={businessName}&number={businessNumber}&date={startDate}&canID={candidateID}&pID={placementID}

I tested that endpoint on a browser with this, but it gives me a JSON with "There is no service at this location":
https://mycompany.flowgear.net/bizrules/validation/gstCheck/?name=ZV Consulting Inc.&number=83848 5183&date=09/02/2014&canID=309731&pID=3835

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding  to POST so you can't open the URL in a browser as your browser is performing a GET. To test you'd need to use the Postman plugin and set the method to POST.

One thing to note though is that Postman makes cross origin requests so you need to set Allowed Origins to * in your Flowgear site detail screen (same place you set your vanity domain).